# Deploying resource adapters on TomEE

Tags: java, apache-tomee, jca

We are trying to migrate from GlassFish to TomEE however we are experiencing troubles deploying our custom resource adapters on TomEE. On GlassFish it is just a matter of deploying RAR file, configuring resource adapter config and that is all. How can we do the same on TomEE with minimal changes to our code?

Comment: What exactly are these troubles you are experiencing? Giving a bit more detail might help you get a better answer. Also, just because GlassFish does something does not immediately imply all J2EE containers do it too. GlassFish could implement additional functionality that is not required for J2EE compliance.

Comment: Yes, I fully agree, however I couldn't find a good step-by-step guide on how to deploy resource adapters on TomEE and I am not even sure if we are doing it right. For example, we deployed our RAR file to /webapps directory, but how to reference it? Where to configure the resource adapter implementation, how to auto inject configuration properties? We've tried adding it in tomee.xml, but we got a `ClassNotFound` exception even though the adapter is deployed.

Answer (score 1):

basically go to tomee.xml, ensure this line is not commented:

```
 <Deployments dir="apps" />
```

If apps folder doesn't exist create it (same level as webapps) and put the rar inside

Comment: How do you configure it tomee.xml? Say you have a rar named "xyz.rar" and it it into apps

Comment: You can configure it through system properties <ra name>.<property>=value

ra name is logged at startup

alternative is to define connector as plain resources using class-name and then it is just tomee resources but should work almost the same